# Haskell group elements in the list and concatenate different adjacent element together

Tags: haskell

The `group` function in `Data.List` can group the same element in a list
Input:

```
import Data.List(group)
group "mississippi time"
```

Output:

```
["m","i","ss","i","ss","i","pp","i"," ","t","i","m","e"]
```

How to modify the `group` function to group the different adjacent elements together?

Expect:

```
["mi","ss","i","ss","i","pp","i time"]
```

Below is my WRONG solution.

I try to group the same elements and then group the different elements. When grouping different elements, I also check the length of each element. Since after `groupSame`, different elements are left alone.

```
-- |
-- >>> groupSame "mississippi time"
-- ["m","i","ss","i","ss","i","pp","i"," ","t","i","m","e"]
groupSame :: String -> [String]
groupSame [] = []
groupSame (x:xs) = (x : takeWhile (== x) xs) : groupSame (dropWhile (== x) xs)
-- >>> groupDiff ["m","i","ss","i","ss","i","pp","i"," ","t","i","m","e"]
-- ["mi","ss","i","ss","i","pp","i time"]
groupDiff :: [String] -> [String]
groupDiff [] = []
groupDiff [x] = [x]
groupDiff (x:y:xs)
 |length x > 1 && length y > 1 =  x:y : groupDiff xs 
 |length x > 1 && length y ==1 =  x: groupDiff (y:xs)
 |length x ==1 && length y > 1 =  x:y: groupDiff xs
 |length x ==1 && length y ==1 =  (x++y): groupDiff xs
```

The expected output is above the `groupDiff` signature.
However I got:

```
["mi","ss","i","ss","i","pp","i"," t","im","e"]
```

Comment: `groupDiff` never groups more than 2 single elements. It needs `++` whenever `y` is a single element *and* `x` is *either single or was produced by a previous `groupDiff`*. You can check for the latter condition in a number of ways, for example by comparing the first two elements of `x`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.  Yeah, I found the main error is the last case. When the length of x and length of y equals 1, I need to check xs's first, second, and next elements. If there are SINGLE (length == 1) elements, I need to concatenate those. But I don't know how to concatenate (x++y) with the potential SIGNLE in xs. Maybe the first is SINGLE ( need ++ ), but maybe the first is a duplication (need : ).

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/fEGW9njvb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```hs
 map concat $ groupBy (\x y -> all ((== 1) . length) [x, y]) $ group "mississippi time"
```

I guess the lambda can be shortened somehow.

I guess `(== 1) . length` could be named `isSingleton`.

And, it could be implemented as `null . tail` to save some parenthesis, fwiw:

```hs
 map concat $ groupBy (\x y -> all (null . tail) [x, y]) $ group "mississippi time"
```

With some more playing, you can even get rid of variables `x` and `y` and write it in point-free style, provided you write an alternative of `all` for pairs,

```hs
all' p (a, b) = p a && p b
map concat $ groupBy (curry $ all' (null . tail)) $ group "mississippi time"
```

but this is likely less readable.

---

You need `import Data.List (groupBy)` too.

---

Somebody else explained to you in a comment why your solution does not work.

My point, however, is that you shouldn't reach for such complicated solutions in the first place.

Hand-made recursion is a powerful tool, but for such a simple tast is just too much powerful; indeed, you get lost into details.

If you know that you just want to *group* things in some way, then reach out for functions that are for grouping, like `group` and `groupBy`, and see how you can combine them together to get what you want.

That's how I crafted my solution (which, performance-wise, might be not optimal), by just writing down what I wanted to do,

- group letters by equality (thus obtaining strings of different lengths)
- group together the adjacent strings that have length 1
- concatenate the strings in each of the groups

and then extracting the functions I need from the key parts of my plan:

- *group by equality*: that's what `group` does
- *group strings that have length 1*: `groupBy` allows grouping given a predicate other than equality, `length` can compute the length, and `(== 1)` is for checking if a number is 1
- *concatenate the strings*: `concat` does just that (for any list, not just strings, btw)
- *in each of the groups*: that means I have to `map` on the list of groups.

Given the above, I got here:

```hs
 map concat $ groupBy (\x y -> doTheyGoTogether) $ group "mississippi time"
```

where I knew `doTheyGoTogether` would use `(== 1) . length` somehow. Not a huge leap to understand that `(== 1) . length` should be true for *all* of `x` and `y`: `doTheyGoTogether = all ((== 1) . length)`.

---

P.S: [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/) is your friend.

Comment: I've moved the wrong solution to the question part. Thanks for the suggestion. And would you mind checking my answer?

Comment: Can't now, but I'll try to give a look at it later today.